# How to attach test report in PR on GitHub

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, pull-request

We are trying one attempt to provide the unit test reports in PR on GitHub. Now two ways at least I can think of are,

1. Attach file in PR and
2. Upload the unit test results on some web portal and provide the link to that in PR.

Now, I just want to know are there any other better ways to do it ? Also in case of first option, I don't see the .html file can be attached to PR so any idea on this?

FYI: We have unit test results in xml as well as html format and we want to upload html format reports.

Comment: You should automate all that stuff. That can be done with what @Adil B said in his answer.

Comment: yes @marcogmonteiro. We want to automate this. But our expectation is bit different and have added comment below on Adil B's answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Github Statuses API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) and a webhook to call a CI service that runs your unit tests on each Pull Request and responds with a Status and test report. This will create a link to your unit test report on each Pull Request which users can click on to see results.

There are several services that offer this capability like CircleCI, Jenkins, and TravisCI, which you can link up to Pull Requests by [following a tutorial](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/building-a-ci-server/) - create a pull request webhook in your GitHub repo, and set your CI service up to respond to each webhook call with a Status.

Comment: Thanks @Adil B for your time. The expectation here is bit different. The reports which we want to upload are from our local. We work on forked branches(which are not configured on build server) and then raise PR from forked to upstream and once that is merged, then only the CI triggers the build and tests results published. We don't want to use these results. So what we want basically is do your changes on local, commit and get the unit test results by running tests on local itself and attach those in the PR so that reviewer can have look then and there itself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - your best option is to upload your local test results to a web portal, and then call the Github Status API to put a nice link to those results on your pull request. You can even write a script to run manually which will run your tests, upload the results, and make the Status API call after you've created a pull request.

Comment: Yes @Adil B. Thanks for the suggestion.